# How to properly pronounce Lur'e for a English speaker

Tags: произношение

([Anatolij Isakovič Lur'ie](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatolij_Isakovi%C4%8D_Lur%27ie)) A. I. Lur'e was a great mathematician from USSR, however no one that I know of knows how to properly pronounce his name, especially last name.

Can a Russian speaker guide a English speaker to properly pronounce his name?

---

А. И. Лурье был великий математик из СССР , однако никто из тех, кого я знаю, не знает, как правильно произносить его имя, особенно фамилию.

Может ли носитель русского языка  обьяснить носителю английского, как правильно произносить это имя ?

Comment: I suppose it's French second name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would spell the pronunciation this way: "Anatoly ie-ssakovich loo-rr-yeah".

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how to pronounce ''rr', maybe I need to roll my tongue? How about his first name..is it pronounced as I think "ana-too-leech", "isa-co-vick"?

Comment: Just say it any way you say "r", f.e. in "read". Or like in Spanish or Italian. I added the first name to the answer.

Answer (score 16):

The same way you pronounce "Fourier". The both are French surnames.

Answer (score 4):

[IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) transcription should be like this:

> ɐnɐtˈolʲɪj ɪsˈakəvʲɪt͡ɕ lurʲjˈe

Considering "how to pronounce that Russian r-r-r", you may look into [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_flaps) which kindly explains that it's "dental apical palatalized tap" or sometimes "dental apical palatalized trill". This essentially means that you have to tap your upper teeth with the tip of your tongue (and possibly even to make it to reverberate). But I doubt you can do such a trick without practicing a couple of weeks ;-) At least when I was about seven years old, I had to visit my speech therapist for about a fortnight to improve my native Russian speech skill and to learn to spell that damned "r-r-r" flawlessly.

Comment: That's all correct but I'd mention that there is actually no need to "trill" R in Лурье. On the other hand, pronouncing a 'soft R' might also be not easy for an English-speaker...

Comment: @A.Toumantsev `no need to "trill" R` Yet there's still need to tap it.

Comment: Без этого никак :) Хотя... многие, например, картавят (или грассируют) - там "тап"ать не надо, можно ли это назвать неправильным произношением? ;)

Comment: @A.Toumantsev Можно и даже нужно. Раньше в школах это специально проверяли и обязывали посещать логопеда. Как сейчас не знаю.

Comment: щас забанят. оффтоп и чат :) Закончил.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips that can help you in similar situations in future - just search youtube and it's pretty straightforward to find some video mentioning this particular person.

This is found in 2 minutes:
https://youtu.be/JuW1rRcgzoA?t=16s

If you are a MacOS user then pretty often (but not always, that's for sure), this can give a hint:

> say -v Milena Лурье

By the way Лурье is pronounced by Milena (it's voice used for Russian) perfectly.